# Is it possible to list Docker images with a size less than 10MB?

Tags: docker

I tried using this command to list Docker images with a size less than 10MB:

```
> docker images --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}\t{{.Size}}' | awk '{ if ($2 < "10MB") print $0 }'

registry.cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/chat-server:ac9b7e52b86a5c86fdd7b613a211e33247018ad3 1.84GB
cruise-radar:latest 1.11GB
busybox:latest  1.41MB
rust:1.54-bullseye  1.5GB
```

It seems that it is not working as expected. Am I missing something?

Comment: the issue may be that awk doesn't understand "10MB" as being anything other than a string, so you're effectively comparing strings, and `"1.11GB"` is "lexically" less than `"10MB"` - perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45616580/converting-kb-and-gb-to-mb-in-bash) will help

Answer (score 2):

As @JaromandaX mentioned in a comment, the problem is that `docker images` produces human-readable size information like `10MB` or `1.1GB`.

While it is possible to transform these values by parsing the suffix and converting them all into bytes, there is another alternative: you can interact directly with the Docker API rather than using the `docker images` command; the advantage here is that the API reports the image size in bytes, so no conversion is necessary.

Using `curl`:

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/images/json |
  jq -r '.[]|select(.Size < 10485760)|[.RepoTags[0], .Size]|@tsv'
```

On my system this produce something like:

```
serjs/go-socks5-proxy:latest    4675775
chedched/foo:latest     7282688
cilium/pwru:latest      4263936
alpinelinux/darkhttpd:latest    5618779
traefik/whoami:latest   6508005
alpine:latest   5544164
containous/whoami:latest        7373346
.
.
.
```